# Understanding the theorem about the almost disjoint sets partial order

Tags: set-theory

I have read the Kunen's set theory. But I get a struck to understand the proof of a theorem.

> Let $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ be a family of pairwise almost disjoint sets, then we define $(\Bbb{P}_\mathcal{A},\le)$ as $\Bbb{P}_\mathcal{A}=\{\langle s,F\rangle : s\in [\omega]^{<\omega},\,F\in[\mathcal{A}]^{<\omega}\}$ and $\langle s,F\rangle \le \langle s',F'\rangle$  iff $s\subset s'$, $F\subset F'$ and $x\cap s'\subset s$ for each $x\in F$.
>
> ---
>
> **Lemma 2.8.** In $\Bbb{P}_\mathcal{A}$, $\langle s,F\rangle$ and $\langle s',F'\rangle$ are compatible iff $x\cap s'\subset s$ for all $x\in F$ and $x\cap s\subset s'$ for all $x\in F'$.
>
> ---
>
> **Lemma 2.10.** If $G$ is a filter in $\Bbb{P}_\mathcal{A}$ and $\langle s,F\rangle \in G$ then $x\cap d_G\subset s$ for each $x\in F$
> (Where $d_G:=\bigcup\{s\mid\exists F:\langle s,F\rangle \in G\}$.)
>
> **Proof.** If $\langle s',F'\rangle\in G$ then $\langle s',F'\rangle$ and $\langle s,F\rangle$ are compatible, so by Lemma 2.8, $x\cap s'\subset s$ for all $x\in F$.

I don't understand the proof of Lemma 2.10. Especially, I don't understand $\langle s',F'\rangle\in G$ implies the compatibility of $\langle s,F\rangle$ and $\langle s',F'\rangle$.  In this book there is no proofs of this statement (as I know) and I don't know how to prove this statement. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x \in F$, note that for any $\langle s^\prime , F^\prime \rangle \in G$ we have that $\langle s^\prime , F^\prime \rangle , \langle s , F \rangle$ are compatible -- since $G$ is a ***filter*** and $\langle s , F \rangle$ also belongs to $G$ -- so by Lemma 2.8 it follows that $x \cap s^\prime \subseteq s$.

It then follows that $x \cap d_G = x \cap \bigcup_{\langle s^\prime , F^\prime \rangle \in G} s^\prime = \bigcup_{\langle s^\prime , F^\prime \rangle \in G} ( x \cap s^\prime ) \subseteq s$.

---

Recall that given a poset $\langle \mathcal{P} , \preceq \rangle$, a (nonempty) subset $F \subseteq \mathcal{P}$ is a *filter* if

- whenever $p,q \in \mathcal{P}$ and $p \preceq q$, then $p \in F$ implies $q \in F$;
- whenever $p,q \in F$, then $p,q$ there is an $r \in F$ with $r \preceq p , q$.

This second condition implies that every two elements of a filter are compatible as elements of the poset.